# Button not displaying fetch results to the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a currency converter app and it will retrieve currency value from the API and multiply with the text input for the result. Both the API result and Text input are stored in State and passing as props to the  Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';
import DisplayResult from './src/DisplayResult'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currency:'',
    pokeList: '',
  }
  placeNameChangeHandler=(val)=>{
    this.setState({currency:val});
  }
    // console.log(this.state.currency);
  async findCurrency () {
    try {
      //Assign the promise unresolved first then get the data using the json method. 
      const pokemonApiCall = await fetch('https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=KWD_INR&compact=ultra&apiKey={my_api_Key}');
      const pokemon = await pokemonApiCall.json();
      this.setState({pokeList: pokemon['KWD_INR']});
      // console.log(pokemon);
  } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
  };
  <DisplayResult convert={this.state.pokeList} result={this.state.currency} />

 }


  render() {

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
        placeholder="Currency"
        value = {this.state.currency}
        onChangeText={this.placeNameChangeHandler}

        />
        <Button 
        title="Search"
        onPress={this.findCurrency.bind(this)}
        />
          </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

DisplayResult

```
const DisplayResult =(props)=>{
    const {convert,result} = props
    console.log(convert);
    return (
        <View>
        <Text>{result*convert}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    }
export default DisplayResult;
```

I am trying to pass the API result and text input to the display component and this will multiply the values and will give the result.

Now this is not functioning or  giving result

why this is not showing and where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `findCurrency` method you just "call" the `DisplayResult` without returning it, but I don't think this is the good method to display your result.

You can use your component directly within the `render` method by testing your state variables, like this :

```
findCurrency = async () => {
try {
  const pokemonApiCall = await fetch(
    "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=KWD_INR&compact=ultra&apiKey={my_api_Key}"
  );
  const pokemon = await pokemonApiCall.json();
  this.setState({ pokeList: pokemon["KWD_INR"] }); // You set your "pokeList" variable up
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
}
}
```

Note that you remove the DisplayResult call here and the function became an arrowed function, then in your render method use the test to make your result appear only if `pokeList` isn't empty :

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Currency"
      value={this.state.currency}
      onChangeText={this.placeNameChangeHandler}
    />
    <Button title="Search" onPress={this.findCurrency.bind(this)} />
    {this.state.pokeList !== "" && (
      <DisplayResult
        convert={this.state.pokeList}
        result={this.state.currency}
      />
    )}
  </View>
);
}
```

Then, you don't have to bind your function in the onPress method like this, JavaScript immediately calls the function if you do this, instead, use arrow functions, you can access `this` by doing so in your function AND the onPress method doesn't call it if you don't click on the button, you just have to specify which function to execute when clicked :

```
<Button title="Search" onPress={this.findCurrency} />
```

If you have parameters in your function, use an arrow function instead :

```
<Button title="Search" onPress={() => yourFunction(param)} />
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: i can see the result but its showing  while entering the text and without pressing the button

Comment: Answer edited (findCurrency method then following), please take a look.

Comment: its the same, its showing result when entering the text and not while pressing button

Comment: My apologies, I wrote "await" insead of "async" in the function name and I forgot the uppercase at "pokeList" in the condition, it's corrected, now it should work.

Comment: its the same  showing result when entering the text and not while pressing button

Comment: It works perfectly by my side, read the whole answer again and check step by step

Comment: what happens second time when you input value in the textinput.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194424/discussion-between-tomafa06-and-karamzov).

Answer (score 0):

try using conditional rendering,
if data fetched, then only render.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,Button } from 'react-native';
import DisplayResult from './src/DisplayResult'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currency: '',
    pokeList: '',
  }
  placeNameChangeHandler=(val)=>{
    this.setState({currency:val});
  }
    // console.log(this.state.currency);
  this.findCurrency.bind(this);
  async findCurrency () {
    try {
      //Assign the promise unresolved first then get the data using the json method. 
      const pokemonApiCall = await fetch('https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=KWD_INR&compact=ultra&apiKey={my_api_Key}');
      const pokemon = await pokemonApiCall.json();
      this.setState({pokeList: pokemon['KWD_INR']});
      // console.log(pokemon);
  } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
  };

 }


  render() {

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
        placeholder="Currency"
        value = {this.state.currency}
        onChangeText={this.placeNameChangeHandler}

        />
        <Button 
        title="Search"
        onPress={this.findCurrency()}
        />
        </View>
        {
        if(this.state.pokeList !== '' || this.state.currency !== '') ?
        <DisplayResult convert={this.state.pokeList} result={this.state.currency} />  : <div></div>
         }

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to press button then see.

Comment: returns the error Text string must be rendered within a text component

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your function like that :

```js
const findCurrency = async() => {
    // ...
};
```

and call it like that

```js
<Button 
    title="Search"
    onPress={() => this.findCurrency()}
/>
```

I personnaly never use `.bind` because I think this is very unclear.